# Download video from social media in Web view

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, webview

I want to download videos from facebook in Web view. Initially I opened the facebook in web view but on any video click facebook did not provide the url of the video.

I have already used web view delegate methods to get the url of any web view link click but facebook did not provide any URL. Any help.

Comment: Hello! Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316378/download-video-file-using-webview

Comment: Well this is in Android. I want to know whether is this possible in iOS native. The scenario is I have successfully opened facebook in iOS web view. On any video click it shows a popup displaying "Do you want to download a video." The problem is facebook did not provide the url of inside links in Web view. Any help

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, you need to use the graph api

Comment: Have you found your solution